How do I fix the faces of a bevel looking pinched when smooth shading?
When I try to bevel the edges of a corner, the faces of the bevel end up looking pinched when I turn on smooth shading. I've tried a weighted normals modifier and shade smooth by angle but nothing changes. What can I do to get rid of this?

Blend file:


It doesn't look like you can avoid that (it is the shading between these very long faces and the perpendicular ones) unless you add topology (image) or you could give it a Subdivision Surface modifier:

